# What is the difference between the various tiling modes in KWin, and how do I use them?

Tags: kde, window-manager, kwin, tiling-wm

There are 3 tiling modes in KDE: spiral, columns and floating. What does each do and how do make them work for me? For example, spiral seems to cut my screen in half then the next half another way. Is it possible to adjust it so that it's like 2/3? I don't understand how to make use of float.

Perhaps someone could explain what each is for (or one for each answer) and how they can be used and tuned.

[image: System Settings, Window Behavior, Window Behavior, Advanced, showing tiling settings]

Comment: Floating simply means "Untiled" in every other tiling window manager. But KDE's implementation of tiling is incredibly buggy, and incredibly badly documented. If its tiling you want, ditch KDM and use something else. If its not tiling you want, ditch it.   Generally, spiral isn't resizable, and one of those spiral parts recurses infinitely till you have a 1x1 window in the bottom-right of your screen.

Comment: @Kent I just wanted to play with it

Comment: @kent, you also realize you could answer the question right?

Comment: I know, I just didn't have enough to actually form a real answer with, I attempted it, but then resolved to comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

Floating means 'untiled', spiral places windows in a spiral form and column tiles them vertically.

PS: answer mostly taken from Kent's comment.